# Anyone any idea why Exchange Web Services (EWS) from Microsoft gives me an (500) "An internal server error occurred" on bindToFolder?

Tags: java, netbeans, exchangewebservices

As a RPGLE programmer I was asked to convert an IMAP mail poller to EWS. So I'm a bit out of my comfort zone.

With all documentation I managed to cobble a lot of pieces together, but it looks like I'm missing a vital piece because the program keep crashing at Folder folder = service.bindToFolder(folderId, propertySet);

It first I thought it had something to do with authorization. But then I found a little program `EwsEditor` at Github which works just fine.

Could someone point me to what I am missing?

With all documentation I managed to cobble a lot of pieces together. My testing code:

```
package test.ewstest;

import com.microsoft.aad.msal4j.ClientCredentialFactory;
import com.microsoft.aad.msal4j.ClientCredentialParameters;
import com.microsoft.aad.msal4j.ConfidentialClientApplication;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.net.URI;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Properties;
import microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.core.ExchangeService;
import microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.core.PropertySet;
import microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.core.enumeration.misc.ConnectingIdType;
import microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.core.enumeration.misc.ExchangeVersion;
import microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.core.enumeration.property.BasePropertySet;
import microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.core.enumeration.property.WellKnownFolderName;
import microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.core.enumeration.search.FolderTraversal;
import microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.core.service.schema.FolderSchema;
import microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.credential.TokenCredentials;
import microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.misc.ImpersonatedUserId;
import microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.property.complex.FolderId;
import microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.property.complex.Mailbox;
import microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.search.FindFoldersResults;
import microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.search.FolderView;
import microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.core.service.folder.Folder;
import org.apache.log4j.LogManager;
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;

public class EwsTest {

    static String exchangeUser;
    static String exchangeTenant;
    static String exchangeClientId;
    static String exchangeClientSecret;
    
    static ExchangeService service;
    static Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(EwsTest.class.getName());
    static Properties properties = new Properties();
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            properties.load(new FileInputStream(System.getProperty("user.dir") + File.separator + "EwsTest.properties"));
            exchangeUser = properties.getProperty("user");
            exchangeTenant = properties.getProperty("tenant");
            exchangeClientId = properties.getProperty("client");
            exchangeClientSecret = properties.getProperty("secret");

            createConnection();
            displayFolders();
        }
        catch (Exception ex) {
            logger.error(ex.getMessage(), ex);
        }
    
    }
    
    static void createConnection() throws Exception {
        service = new ExchangeService(ExchangeVersion.Exchange2010_SP2);
        service.getHttpHeaders().put("X-AnchorMailbox",exchangeUser);
        service.getHttpHeaders().put("X-PublicFolderMailbox",exchangeUser);
        service.setCredentials(new TokenCredentials(createOauthToken()));
        service.setImpersonatedUserId(new ImpersonatedUserId(ConnectingIdType.SmtpAddress, exchangeUser));
        service.setUrl(new URI("https://outlook.office365.com/EWS/Exchange.asmx"));
        }

    static String createOauthToken() throws Exception {
        ConfidentialClientApplication app = ConfidentialClientApplication.builder(
                exchangeClientId,
                ClientCredentialFactory.createFromSecret(exchangeClientSecret))
                .authority("https://login.microsoftonline.com/" + exchangeTenant + "/")
                .build();            
        ClientCredentialParameters clientCredentialParam = ClientCredentialParameters.builder(
                Collections.singleton("https://outlook.office365.com/.default"))
                .build();
        return app.acquireToken(clientCredentialParam).get().accessToken();
    }

    static void displayFolders() throws Exception {
        PropertySet propertySet = new PropertySet(BasePropertySet.IdOnly);
        propertySet.add(FolderSchema.DisplayName);
                
        FolderView view = new FolderView(100);
        view.setPropertySet(propertySet);
        view.setTraversal(FolderTraversal.Deep);

        Mailbox mailbox = new Mailbox(exchangeUser);
        
        FolderId folderId = new FolderId(WellKnownFolderName.MsgFolderRoot, mailbox);
        
        logger.info("service.bindToFolder");
        Folder folder = service.bindToFolder(folderId, propertySet);
        logger.info("Ok");

        logger.info("service.findFolders");
        FindFoldersResults findFolderResults = service.findFolders(folder.getId(), view);
        logger.info("Ok");

        // find specific folder
        for (Folder f : findFolderResults)
        {
            logger.info(f.getId());
        }
    }
}
```

And my Netbeans maven dependencies:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>test</groupId>
    <artifactId>EwsTest</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-1.2-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.11.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.xml.ws</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxws-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.microsoft.azure</groupId>
            <artifactId>msal4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.13.3</version>
        </dependency>
     <dependency>
      <groupId>com.microsoft.ews-java-api</groupId>
      <artifactId>ews-java-api</artifactId>
      <version>2.0</version>
     </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>19</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>19</maven.compiler.target>
        <exec.mainClass>test.ewstest.EwsTest</exec.mainClass>
    </properties>
</project>
```

I created my EwsTest.properties file and filled it with the keys:

```
user=example@example.nl
client=9999x9xx-xx99-x99x-xx99-xx99x9999x9x
tenant=x99x9999-xx99-9999-xx99-9999xx9x9999
secret=XXxxX!9xx-...-
```

When I run the program, I see that the connection is being build and a token is being exchanged. But it crashes at the statement:

Folder folder = service.bindToFolder(folderId, propertySet);

With an error: The request failed. An internal server error occurred. The operation failed.

```
microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.core.exception.service.remote.ServiceRequestException: The request failed. An internal server error occurred. The operation failed.
    at microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.core.request.SimpleServiceRequestBase.internalExecute(SimpleServiceRequestBase.java:74) ~[ews-java-api-2.0.jar:?]
    at microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.core.request.MultiResponseServiceRequest.execute(MultiResponseServiceRequest.java:158) ~[ews-java-api-2.0.jar:?]
    at microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.core.ExchangeService.bindToFolder(ExchangeService.java:504) ~[ews-java-api-2.0.jar:?]
    at test.ewstest.EwsTest.displayFolders(EwsTest.java:91) ~[classes/:?]
    at test.ewstest.EwsTest.main(EwsTest.java:49) [classes/:?]
Caused by: microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.core.exception.service.remote.ServiceResponseException: An internal server error occurred. The operation failed.
    at microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.core.request.ServiceRequestBase.processWebException(ServiceRequestBase.java:548) ~[ews-java-api-2.0.jar:?]
    at microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.core.request.ServiceRequestBase.validateAndEmitRequest(ServiceRequestBase.java:641) ~[ews-java-api-2.0.jar:?]
    at microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.core.request.SimpleServiceRequestBase.internalExecute(SimpleServiceRequestBase.java:62) ~[ews-java-api-2.0.jar:?]
    ... 4 more
```

I tried several folders like inbox and root but they all give that same error:

```
        FolderId folderId = new FolderId(WellKnownFolderName.MsgFolderRoot, mailbox);
```

But since EwsEditor seems to work, I'm clearly missing something. I tried looking at the code of EwsEditor but that's C# which is even harder to understand for me.

Comment: That exception is unhelpful, but perhaps some of the comments in this [recent Microsoft Tech Community thread](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/exchange/ews-with-oauth-quot-an-internal-server-error-occurred-the/m-p/3609047) might be useful. I have no idea whether they are relevant for your problem, but some users have posted specific code changes they made to resolve that exception.

Comment: Thank you @skomisa. I hadn't seen the last suggestions on than page before, so it's worth a try. And good to know, I'm not the only one with this error. ;)

Comment: The MS Tech community had a few new suggestions.
1. Changing the scope to https://outlook.office365.com/EWS.AccessAsUser.All which results in an error AADSTS1002012 Client credential flows must have a scope value with /.default suffixed.
2. And adding service.getHttpHeaders().put("Authorization", "Bearer " + token); after which I still receive an InternalServerError.
So sadly, this is not the answer.

Comment: My manager decided to go for a solution with Javax.mail IMAP with XOAUTH2 for now.